# "join" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF ,";"

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM `order` join order_detail WHERE order_id = 1578;
```

Could anyone please help me. the word from have a red underline said "from" is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, ";" but i google it and have not thing wrong with it mysql

Comment: Do you want to delete data from only order table or from order_details as well? Why is ON clause missing? 
Check below answer and frame a query like that. Also make sure that foreign key is defined with "ON DELETE CASCADE", in case you want to delete from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mysql` it is necessary to provide the column on which the join is supposed to take place.

So your query should look like:

```sql
DELETE FROM `order` JOIN `order_details` ON <your-join-condition> WHERE order.order_id = 1578;
```